# Minimize number of symbols in calculation with clever substitutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

When I do solve(a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d=0,x) in wxMaxima, I get a big answer. I made use of substitutions to make the calculations more practical:

$$A=\left(27a^2d^2+4b^3d-18abcd+4ac^3-b^2c^2\right)^{1\!/2}$$
$$B={\left(\frac{A}{2\!\cdot\!3^{3/2}a^2}-\frac{27a^2d-9abc+2b^3}{54a^3}\right)}^{1\!/3}$$
$$C=\frac{3ac-b^2}{9a^2B}$$
$$D=\frac12(C-B)-\frac{b}{3a}$$
$$E=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(C+B)$$
$$x_1=B-C-\frac{b}{3a}$$
$$x_2=D+Ei$$
$$x_3=D-Ei$$

Some questions:

1) Is it possible to make a more clever choice of substitutions in this example, so the resulting number of operations is reduced?

2) Is there a general procedure or heuristic for minimizing the number of operations with substitutions? (Is this a branch of mathematics?)

Comment: It looks like your aim is a solution to the general cubic equation. There are some simpler substitutions for this, one to begin with which, after division to make cubic coefficient $1$ removes the 2nd degree term so you get $x^3+cx+d=0$ to solve. From there, or just as a start, try a google on "cubic equation."

Answer (score 0):

I think maxima just uses the general formula for cubic equations. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for example.